# Google Maps Marker Selection

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

greetings,

I am loading markers on a google maps dinamically with xml that comes from a php function

Also I use that XML to build a table with all the locations.

the question is how can I link each table entry to a marker so i can click on that location and it appears the marker centered on my map and open the info window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the marker object, give it an id:

```
var alatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: alatlng,
    title:"Hello World!",
    icon: image
});

marker.setValues({type: "point", id: counter });
marker.setMap(map);
```

Then you can use [addDomListener](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#DomEvents) to add a listener to a click event on your table object (hyperlink etc)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("result" + counter), 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter( latlngbounds.getCenter( ) );
});
```

The bounds of the map are set using:

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );
latlngbounds.extend(alatlng);
```

Not 100% sure this is what you are after from your post, but it should piece together for you.